# expand MNIST - elastic deformations MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I want to augment the MNIST handwritten digits dataset.
In order to do that I want to create for each image an **Elastic Deformations** image respectively.

I read on [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.160.8494&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper, section 2 'Expanding Data Sets through Elastic
Distortions' that they accomplished elastic distortions

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

I tried:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imwarp.html
http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/creating-a-gallery-of-transformed-images.html

without any success.

How can i do that in MATLAB?

How can I create **Elastic Distortion** transformation on an image in **MATLAB**?

Comment: A python implementation can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/fmder/e28813c1e8721830ff9c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely followed the "normalization" method of the displacement field, but I think this can get you quite close

```
img = imread('http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/_images/mnist_2.png');  %// get a digit
```

Compute a random displacement field `dx~U(-1,1)`, `dy~U(-1,1)`:

```
dx = -1+2*rand(size(img)); 
dy = -1+2*rand(size(img));
```

Smoothing and normalizing the field:

```
sig=4; 
alpha=60;
H=fspecial('gauss',[7 7], sig);
fdx=imfilter(dx,H);
fdy=imfilter(dy,H);
n=sum((fdx(:).^2+fdy(:).^2)); %// norm (?) not quite sure about this "norm"
fdx=alpha*fdx./n;
fdy=alpha*fdy./n;
```

The resulting displacement

```
[y x]=ndgrid(1:size(img,1),1:size(img,2));
figure;
imagesc(img); colormap gray; axis image; axis tight;
hold on;
quiver(x,y,fdx,fdy,0,'r');
```

[image]

The final stage - applying the displacement to the actual pixels using [`griddata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) interpolation:

```
new = griddata(x-fdx,y-fdy,double(img),x,y);
new(isnan(new))=0;
```

The resulting digit:

```
figure;
subplot(121); imagesc(img); axis image;
subplot(122); imagesc(new); axis image;
colormap gray
```

[image]

---

BTW, I'm not sure the proposed method (`rand`+`imfilter`) is the most straight-forward way of producing a random smooth deformation, you might consider sampling coefficients for 2-nd or 3-rd degree polynomial deformation,

```
dx = a*x.^2 + b*x.*y + c*y.^2 + d*x + e*y + f;
dy = g*x.^2 + h*x.*y + k*y.^2 + l*x + m*y + n;
```

Comment: It works gr8. I succeed to augment my dataset with this method. before i used 'white gaussian noise' method in order to augment  the dataset. When i used one method at the time i get approximately same results. together i succeed to improve the MSE in 4%.